# `avm install 0.29.0` fails because of `ahash`

Tags: anchor

I am trying to install anchor using `avm install 0.29.0` but got the following error

```
error[E0635]: unknown feature `stdsimd`
  --> /Users/anhdungle/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/ahash-0.8.3/src/lib.rs:99:42
   |
99 | #![cfg_attr(feature = "stdsimd", feature(stdsimd))]
   |                                          ^^^^^^^

   Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
   Compiling rand v0.8.5
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0635`.
error: could not compile `ahash` (lib) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.29.0 (https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor?tag=v0.29.0#fc9fd6d2)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/0h/tf8nh7sj20dgzt8dchfgzwj40000gn/T/cargo-installZHLWZm`.
To reuse those artifacts with a future compilation, set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to that path.
Error: Failed to install 0.29.0, is it a valid version?
```

I have already run `cargo update ahash@0.8.8` and put `ahash = "=0.8.8"` into dependencies in `Cargo.toml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to install anchor by downgrading from `rustc 1.78.0-nightly` to a stable version `rustc 1.76.0` by `rustup override set stable`

Answer (score 1):

Yes anchor 0.29.0 is a valid version.

You can install avm through

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --locked --force
```

If the cargo fails, install the additional dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev
```

then

```
avm install latest
avm use latest
```